# How to convert this scientific notation to a decimal form using C#

Tags: c#, floating-point

In the following code the output `result` produces `6.075378E-05`. I would like to get a decimal form (whatever it is) such as `0.48`, `1.04` etc.:

```
float var1 = 70081.13;
float var2 = 752912.4;
float result = (var1/var2)*100;
```

Comment: isin't the result of this equation 9.308006 ? Also what are you looking for ? a round up ?

Comment: If youre printing out `result` just use the `toString()` method with arguments.... `result.toString("f3")` for example.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier The `result` variable is showing the value as `6.075378E-05` on the ASP.NET page. I would like to display it in a normal decimal form. If `6.075378E-05` is `9.308006` I would like to display it as `9.308006`.

Comment: @KDecker Using your suggestion gives the error `no overload for method ToString takes 1 arguments`

Comment: Please provide the code where you are displaying the value.

Comment: The issue isn't going to be with the calculations above.  Those are correct.  It's with how you are displaying the variable.  You need to show us the code to display that result.

Comment: @KDecker The value is displaying correctly. I just want to make it more understandable for average user. I've verified, by placing a breakpoint on the relevant line on the controller, that the value in the controller and in the view are the same: Controller returns a `ViewModel` named `VM` with a property `VM.result = (var1/var2)*100`. This property is displayed in the `View` as `<div>@Model.result</div>`

Comment: @Vahlkron I agree with you. Please see my latest comment above.  So, as the title of this post says: How do I convert this value to a more readable format in the controller before displaying it

Comment: The notations are just different display formats of the underlying value.  That's why everyone needs to see the code in the view where it's actually written out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the string representation of the result by using `ToString(string)` with your desired format string.  See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f71z6k0c(v=vs.110).aspx).

In your view, this will appear as `@Model.result.ToString("<format string>")`.

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you). I used `@Model.result.ToString("P")` and that displays **0.01%** exactly what I was looking for. Your MSDN linked is of good help for future reference, as well. I'm glad you provided that link while explaining your response.